# How to list subdirectories in Azure blob storage

Tags: list, azure, subdirectory, blobstorage

MS has announced directory like blob storage, and I'm trying to use it like directories.
 Having save some blobs by names:

```
Common\Service1\Type1\Object1
Common\Service1\Type1\Object2
Common\Service1\Type2\Object1
Common\Service1\Type2\Object2
Common\Service1\Type3\Object1
Common\Service1\Type3\Object2
Common\Service1\Type3\Object3
```

I'd like to have possibility to enumerate subdirectories, e.g. I have blobclient referenced to `Common` container name, and I would like to get subcontainers list `Type1, Type2, Type3`. Is it possible to get list of subdirectories in some directory. Using ListBlobs returns full list of blobs within current container.

Comment: Are you talking about Blob Storage or Azure File Service?

Comment: @GauravMantri, Azure Blobstorage

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you would like to list all "subdirectories" in "Common\Service1" directory you can use something like this:

```
    var directory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(@"Common/Service1");
    var folders = directory.ListBlobs().Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();
    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
    }
```

Full code sample:

```
    var random = new Random();
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
    var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test-container");
    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
    string[] objects = new[]
                           {
                               @"Common\Service1\Type1\Object1", @"Common\Service1\Type1\Object2", @"Common\Service1\Type2\Object1",
                               @"Common\Service1\Type2\Object2", @"Common\Service1\Type3\Object1", @"Common\Service1\Type3\Object2",
                               @"Common\Service1\Type3\Object3"
                           };
    foreach (var newObject in objects)
    {
        var newBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(newObject);
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        random.NextBytes(buffer);
        newBlob.UploadFromByteArray(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    }

    var directory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(@"Common/Service1");
    var folders = directory.ListBlobs().Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();
    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
    }
```

This will output Uri for Type1,Type2 and Type3 directory.

Comment: There is mistype in your code, it uses `/` instead of backslash

Comment: Actually it's not. I does not matter how do you get reference for blob `blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference`, both `/` and `\ `  works, but for some reason GetDirectoryReference needs to be with `\ ` (Uri style), I guess it has something to do with directory being just a prefix and all blob prefixes are stored Uri format.

Comment: for me it was enough to find out there's a method like blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(@"Common/Service1");  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Building on [b2zw2a's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26868583/1152054):

- The `@` is only needed when using `\`, not `/`.
- Don't chain `ToList()` after `ListBlobs()`. [`ListBlobs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory.listblobs.aspx) provides lazy loading and will give you better perf.
- Use [`OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) to filter out only the type you want

Giving you:

```
var directory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("Common/Service1");
var folders = directory.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>();
foreach (var folder in folders)
{
    Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var nameList=logoContainer.ListBlobs().Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).Select(x => x.Uri + "").ToList();
```

By using this you can get all the filenames in a single query.